Using MSAL in React, how do you prevent a flash of unauthenticated content before logging out?
My team is using @azure/msal-react to authenticate a user. When the user logs out, we call logoutRedirect():
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';

const { instance } = useMsal();

instance.logoutRedirect({
  postLogoutRedirectUri: '/'
});

When this runs, isAuthenticated becomes false immediately but there is a delay before the user is redirected to the Microsoft logout screen, causing a flash of our unauthenticated template.
import { useIsAuthenticated } from '@azure/msal-react';

const Layout = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

  if(isAuthenticated) {
    return <>Authenticated Template</>;
  } else {
    // this flashes for a second before seeing the Microsoft account logout screen
    return <>Unauthenticated Template</>
  }
}

Is there a way to prevent this flash from occurring?

You can use the logoutInProgress state to track the logout process. When instance.logoutRedirect() is called, it should be set to true to prevent displaying the unauthenticated content prematurely, showing a 'Logging out...' message instead.

You can try my GitHub Repository.

To prevent displaying unauthenticated content while the logout request is in progress, you can use the logoutInProgress state to track the process. Set it to true when instance.logoutRedirect() is called, showing a "Logging out..." message instead.
Here is the complete GitHub repository.
Layout.js :
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useMsal, useIsAuthenticated } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { msalInstance } from "../msalConfig";
import AuthenticatedTemplate from "./AuthenticatedTemplate";
import UnauthenticatedTemplate from "./UnauthenticatedTemplate";

function Layout() {
  const { instance } = useMsal();
  const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();
  const [logoutInProgress, setLogoutInProgress] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hash.includes("id_token")) {
      msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise()
        .then((response) => {
          if (response) {
            console.log("Login successful: ", response);
            setToken(response.accessToken); 
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Login error:", error);
          setError(`Login failed: ${error.message}`);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (logoutInProgress) {
      return <div>Logging out...</div>;
    }
  }, [logoutInProgress]);
  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <AuthenticatedTemplate handleLogout={handleLogout} token={token} />
  ) : (
    <UnauthenticatedTemplate handleLogin={handleLogin} error={error} />
  );

  function handleLogin() {
    msalInstance.loginRedirect({
      scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"], 
      prompt: "select_account",
    }).catch((e) => {
      console.error("Login error:", e);
      setError(`Login failed: ${e.message}`);
    });
  }

  function handleLogout() {
    setLogoutInProgress(true);
    msalInstance.logoutRedirect({
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "/", 
    });
    const cookies = document.cookie.split("; ");
    cookies.forEach(cookie => {
      const cookieName = cookie.split("=")[0];
      document.cookie = `${cookieName}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;`;
    });
  }
}
export default Layout;

msalConfig.js :
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";

export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "<clientID>",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>", 
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000", 
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      logLevel: msal.LogLevel.Verbose, 
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          console.log(`PII-Log: ${message}`);
        } else {
          console.log(`Log: ${message}`);
        }
      },
    },
  },
};
export const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

AuthenticatedTemplate.js :
import React from "react";

function AuthenticatedTemplate({ handleLogout }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome! You are logged in.</h1>
      <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AuthenticatedTemplate;

Output :
The Reactjs application ran successfully, and the login page appeared as shown below:

I selected my account to log in, as below,

After successfully logging in, I was redirected to the Logout page, as shown  below,

I logged out by clicking the Logout button and selected my account to log out without any issues, as shown below.


